# PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name '' is not defined due to special characters in column names Regression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, regression

I am implementing regression. Output_variable is my y variable and input2,  input4, Input5&1, input6-3 are x variables in my regression equation. All these are basically columns in df.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
model = sm.ols(formula='Output_variable ~  Input2 + input4 + Input5&1 + input6-3', data=df)
fitted1 = model.fit()
fitted1.summary()
```

I get error:

```
 PatsyError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-73-20a8ca10f7b8> in <module>
          1 import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
    ----> 2 model = sm.ols(formula='Output_variable ~  Input2 + input4 + Input5&1 + input6-3', data=df)
    
PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name 'Input5' is not defined
```

I get same error for input6 is not defined.

Basically **whenever my column name has special character** like Input5 has & in it and input6 has - sign in it, there is a **trouble** and i get a patsyerror.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```py
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
model = sm.ols(formula='Output_variable ~  Input2 + input4 + Q("Input5&1") + Q("input6-3")', data=df)
fitted1 = model.fit()
fitted1.summary()
```

The problem is in `patsy` which you can't put special chars such as '&' and '-'. Fortunately, the developers addressed this problem and allows a bypass using `Q("full text")`